# Getting rid of ghost/artifact variables as a result of dplyr::filter()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
x <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3))
y <- 1:9
z <- seq(from = 9, to = 81, by = 9)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z); rm(x, y, z)
```

Where I would like to keep just "A" and "C":

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
    filter(x %in% c("A", "C"))
```

But when I `stripchart()` the results, the ghost of "B" is still there:

```
with(df, stripchart(z ~ x, method = "jitter", pch=1))
```

[image]

What argument in my `filter` expression or chain do I need in order to get rid of the "B" artifact/ghost variable.

Comment: Just pipe it to `droplevels`.

Comment: or use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `data.frame` defininion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@joran's suggestion worked:

```
df <- df %>%
    filter(x %in% c("A", "C")) %>%
    droplevels()
```

Thanks!